# Gz(un)compress in PHP and saving to file

Tags: php, compression

Can someone please explain why this code:

```
$str = "StackOverflow"; 
echo $str . " - ";

$strCompressed = gzcompress($str);
//echo $strCompressed . " - ";

$strUncompressed = gzuncompress($strCompressed);
echo $strUncompressed . " - ";
```

gives the expected output of: `StackOverflow - StackOverflow -`

but this code (writing and reading from file):

```
$str = "StackOverflow";
$strCompressed = gzcompress($str);

$file = "test.cache";
$fp = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($fp, $strCompressed);
fclose($fp);

$strCompressed = readfile($file);
echo gzuncompress($strCompressed);
```

does not produce the wated output of `StackOverflow`?

Also, I'm wondering, if I uncoment the commented line of code in the first example (`//echo $strCompressed . " - ";`) the script will output something like this: `StackOverflow - xś.ILÎö/K-JËÉ/`, so as you can see without the second `StackOverflow -` as with that line comented out. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$strCompressed = file_get_contents($file);
echo gzuncompress($strCompressed);
```

`readfile` doesn't return the file's contents but outputs them